# How to solve ODE simultaneously using midpoint method?

Tags: matlab

[Background info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7gmO.png)
[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfzDT.png)

This is my midpoint function file which im not sure about too. I edited the original midpoint function file to suit this question but i dont know if it is correct or not.

```
function [t,a] = midpoint2(dadt,tspan,z0,h)
% [t,y] = midpoint2(dydt,tspan,y0,h)

% uses midpoint method to solve an ODE
%
% INPUTS:
%  - dadt = function handle of the ODE, f(t,a)
%  - tspan = [<initial value>, <final value>] of independent variable
%  - z0 = initial value of dependent variable
%  - h = step size
% OUTPUTS:
%  - t = vector of time
%  - a = vector of solution for degree

% Input Validation: tspan
if ~(tspan(2)>tspan(1))
    error('upper limit must be greater than lower')
end

% define t vector
t = (tspan(1):h:tspan(2))';
n = length(t);
% if necessary, add an additional t so that range goes up to tspan(2)

% Preallocate a to improve efficiency
a = z0*ones(n,1);
% Implement Midpoint method
for i = 1:n-1
    t_half = a(i)+h/2*dadt(t(i),a(i));
    a(i+1) = a(i)+h*(dadt(t(i)+h/2,t_half));
end
```

Comment: "i dont know if it is correct or not." you can check this easily, pick an equation you know how to solve and see if your approximation is close to the true solution.

Comment: Pick a few different differential equations you have the analytical solution and see if your code gives those same answers. Also, compare the results of your code with those from the built-in functions, like the [ode45](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html). Notice also that for small angles, the approximation `sin(theta)~theta` is valid. This results in a linear differential equation that also has a closed form solution. To check if your code is working, start by comparing with some results you know.